# Bandwidth vs database querying

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, performance

I display images that I want the user to be able to delete. I do this with an AJAX request.

Is it best practise to:

1. Pass just the ID of the image, use mysql to find what the filename of that record is, and then delete the file?

OR

2. Pass the ID **and** the src of the image so I can just delete the image right away without looking it up?

One uses more bandwidth, the other more processing power.

Either way I need the ID because I have to do delete the record.

Comment: I would be surprised if it's possible to answer this in the general case without accounting for the different possibilities; not merely the connection speed, bandwidth plan, CPU, drive speed, and so forth, but specific load, business logic, and so on.

Comment: this is a completely unnecessary optimisation to be thinking about. but i'd be concerned about letting a user specify an arbitrary path to be deleted - so you really should be checking `src` and `id` in the database _anyway_, so there's your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting comment to answer because I think it's important.

As far as optimisations go, what you are considering is so trivial so as not to be worth spending any time on.

As far as security nightmares go, allowing the user to specify an arbitrary string to be **deleted** from your file system seems a bit.. careless.

Since you would need to verify that the `src` is correctly paired with the `id`, you would need to be looking this up in the database anyway, which renders your question void.

Comment: ...and, I would suggest, you should verify that the requesting user has permission to delete the object in question.  Of course, as a pedantic DBA, I only ever flag things as deleted, so they're no longer seen... they don't actually go away.

Comment: too bad flagging a row as deleted doesn't free up the disk space of the associated file ;)

Comment: Heh.  Cloud storage.  My "disks" all show 256TB free space. :)

Answer (score 1):

The network payload size of either request (with or without the path name) very likely fits in a single IP packet 1.5KiB even with protocol overhead.  So, the difference in network bandwidth doesn't matter very much.

Plus, unless your application is some kind of extraordinary special case, image deletion is probably a rarer opteration than most.  I wouldn't worry about this overhead if I were you.

I suggest you spend your effort on security concerns instead.  Does the user making the request have the right to erase the particular image? Is it easy for an untrusted user to do destructive wholesale deletion?